# Emacs on cygwin: How to open file/directory on windows share

Tags: microsoft-windows, tramp, cygwin

With Emacs running on Windows (without `cygwin`) I am able to open a remote (windows share) directory with `C-x C-f //IPADDRESS/d$ RET` command. With Emacs on cygwin, I tried `/smb:IPADDRESS:/d$$ RET`. However, I got the below error message,

`Host 'IPADDRESS' looks like a remote host, 'smb' can only use the local host.`

The earlier `//IPADDRESS/DIR` syntax too didn't work.

Can anyone please help (I also tried using my username in the `smb` URL but got the same error)?

**EDIT:** I found out from the post https://superuser.com/questions/102233/how-to-go-to-remote-directory-in-cygwin that cygwin treats UNC paths as local. More information is at https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#unc-paths. So the solution is to do `C-x C-f //machine/shareddir RET` to browse the remote directory assuming you don't have to provide different credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tramp's smb method is not activated for cygwin. See `tramp-smb.el`:

```
(unless (memq system-type '(cygwin windows-nt))
  (add-to-list 'tramp-methods
    `(,tramp-smb-method
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Why this is not be supported? Also is there any other way I can access remote files from Emacs on cygwin if Tramp smb is restricted?

Comment: Well, it is 15+ years old code, I don't remember. If you have the `smbclient` available in cygwin, edit the code snippet to not kick off cygwin, and try it. If it works for you, pls report, and I'll change it in Tramp.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looks like cygwin doesn't provide a smbclient. I stumbled upon a post where the person has compiled smbclient for windows at http://allandynes.com/2016/05/samba-client-for-windows-smbclient-exe-v3-6-25/. Interested users can try it out and post the outcome here. Meanwhile, I am editing my question to include the answer I got from another Q&A.